# The usort function does not seem to work, why?

Tags: php

I fail to see what I am doing wrong with usort. Any ideas?

```
use DependencyResolver;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class DependencyResolverTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testComplex(){
        $resolver = new DependencyResolver();
        $graph = array(
            'A' => array('C'),
            'B' => array(),
            'C' => array()
        );
        $graph2 = array(
            'C' => array(),
            'B' => array(),
            'A' => array('C')
        );
        $output = $resolver->resolveDependencyGraph($graph);
        $output2 = $resolver->resolveDependencyGraph($graph2);
        unset($output[array_search('B', $output)]);
        unset($output2[array_search('B', $output2)]);
        $this->assertEquals($output, $output2);
    }
}

use Exception;

class DependencyResolver {

    protected $graph;
    protected $nestedKeys;

    public function resolveDependencyGraph(array $graph):array {
        $this->graph = $graph;
        $this->nestedKeys = array();
        $keys = array_keys($this->graph);
        $success = usort($keys, array($this, 'sortByDependency'));
        if (!$success)
            throw new Exception('Something went wrong.');
        unset($this->graph);
        unset($this->nestedKeys);
        return $keys;
    }

    protected function sortByDependency(string $left, string $right):int {
        if ($this->isDependentFrom($left, $right))
            $result = 1;
        elseif ($this->isDependentFrom($right, $left))
            $result = -1;
        else
            $result = 0;
        return $result;
    }

    protected function isDependentFrom(string $key, string $possibleDependency):bool {
        $isDependent = false;
        if (in_array($possibleDependency, $this->graph[$key]))
            $isDependent = true;
        else {
            $this->nestedKeys[] = $key;
            foreach ($this->graph[$key] as $dependencyOfKey){
                if (in_array($dependencyOfKey, $this->nestedKeys))
                    throw new Exception('Circular dependency.');
                if ($this->isDependentFrom($dependencyOfKey, $possibleDependency)){
                    $isDependent = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            array_pop($this->nestedKeys);
        }
        return $isDependent;
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorting $keys doesn't change the original array.

Comment: I think you may want `uksort()`. This passes the keys to the comparison function and sorts the array elements.

Comment: @inf3rno it is not if you read the docs and use a decent IDE.

Comment: @Barmar I want to solve a dependency graph with it. I modified the test meanwhile. For `{a:["c"],b:[],c:[]}` it should give `['c','a','b']` or `['b','c','a']`, but it gives `['a','b','c']`, which means in my book that the sorting algorithm PHP is using is broken, or maybe I completely misunderstood something. I rather do this manually. At least in my use case I can do so, but I am curious if the language is broken or I don't understand how sorting goes. Not to mention the confusing function names "uasort", "usort", "uksort", etc.

Comment: @CornelRaiu Haha.

Comment: That result doesn't have the contents of the original array, I don't see how any of the sort functions could produce that.

Comment: @Barmar Probably the comparator is not good. I mean A <=> B and C<=> B gives 0 which means they don't change place, while A <=> C gives -1, so the order it not absolute and it confuses the sorting algorithm.

Comment: Most sorting algorithms require that the comparison function describe a total order. If there are inconsistent results when comparing A vs B and B vs A, you won't get predictable results.

Comment: @Barmar It works for a tree, but if the elements are from independent trees, then it fails. So my code has the bug. I need to separate the trees and sort them independently and concatting the results. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it meanwhile. The sorting fails when there are dependency subgraphs, which are not connected to each other and when they are mixed up, their nodes can block sorting each other, because the comparator returns 0 for them. So I had to separate the subgraphs and now it is working fine. Not the best code I wrote, but I don't have time to optimize it.

```
use Exception;

class DependencyResolver {

    protected $graph;
    protected $nestedKeys;

    public function resolveDependencyGraph(array $graph):array {
        $this->graph = $graph;
        $this->nestedKeys = array();
        $result = array();
        foreach ($this->separateSubGraphs() as $subGraph)
            $result = array_merge($result, $this->sortSubGraph($subGraph));
        unset($this->graph);
        unset($this->nestedKeys);
        return $result;
    }

    protected function separateSubGraphs():array {
        $keys = array_keys($this->graph);
        $pending = array_combine($keys, $keys);
        $subGraphs = array();
        while (!empty($pending)){
            $first = array_pop($pending);
            $subGraph = array();
            $subPending = array($first);
            while(!empty($subPending)){
                $current = array_pop($subPending);
                $subGraph[] = $current;
                foreach ($this->graph[$current] as $dependency)
                    if (isset($pending[$dependency])){
                        $subPending[] = $dependency;
                        unset($pending[$dependency]);
                    }
                foreach ($pending as $possibleDependent)
                    if (in_array($current, $this->graph[$possibleDependent])){
                        $subPending[] = $possibleDependent;
                        unset($pending[$possibleDependent]);
                    }
            }
            $subGraphs[] = $subGraph;
        }
        return $subGraphs;
    }


    protected function sortSubGraph(array $keys):array {
        $success = usort($keys, array($this, 'sortByDependency'));
        if (!$success)
            throw new Exception('Something went wrong.');
        return $keys;
    }

    protected function sortByDependency(string $left, string $right):int {
        if ($this->isDependentFrom($left, $right))
            $result = 1;
        elseif ($this->isDependentFrom($right, $left))
            $result = -1;
        else
            $result = 0;
        return $result;
    }

    protected function isDependentFrom(string $key, string $possibleDependency):bool {
        $isDependent = false;
        if (in_array($possibleDependency, $this->graph[$key]))
            $isDependent = true;
        else {
            $this->nestedKeys[] = $key;
            foreach ($this->graph[$key] as $dependencyOfKey){
                if (in_array($dependencyOfKey, $this->nestedKeys))
                    throw new Exception('Circular dependency.');
                if ($this->isDependentFrom($dependencyOfKey, $possibleDependency)){
                    $isDependent = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            array_pop($this->nestedKeys);
        }
        return $isDependent;
    }

}
```